# why does this bone scale weird when it's at an angle

Tags: rigging, armature

[image]
Do they only work when they're straight i dont get this?

Comment: Difficult to tell from that image. I suggest you share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to paste the link into your question.

Answer (score 3):

You've scaled and stretched your armature in *Object* mode, now you need to apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) before posing the armature.